# knockout updating table results with field outside table

Tags: knockout.js

I have a text box outside my table that knockout is creating.  I want to have the user update that field and in turn update the data in the table.  I have created the following fiddle that shows what I am trying to do.

I have used

```
self.final = ko.computed(function() {
return (self.sales() + $("#increase").val() * self.multiplier();
});
```

but it doesn't seem to cause the table to update.

fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Rarewood/SdL87/5/

I am trying to use this simple answer to answer my more complex problem.  I am using a json datasource.

```
        self.getCalcData = function (mypath,index) {
            self.calcList.removeAll();
            $.getJSON(mypath, function (allData) {
                var mappedLogs = $.map(allData, function (item) { return new CalcList(item) });
                self.calcList(mappedLogs);
            });
        };
```

with this data function

```
function CalcList(data) {
        var self = this;
        self.category = ko.observable(data.CATEGORY);
        self.sales = ko.observable(data.SALES);
        self.growthinput = ko.observable();
};
```

and viewmodel

```
function LogEntryViewModel() {
        var self = this; 
        self.calcList = ko.observableArray([]);
        self.sales = ko.observable();
        self.growthinput = ko.observable();
};
```

I can't quiet get that first answer to work with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to make it work is letting knockout to do the binding also for your textbox.

Create a new observable property on your `viewmodel`

```
self.increase = ko.observable(200);
```

And bind it in your view:

```
<input id="increase" type="text" data-bind="value: increase"/>
```

Then pass this property into your `Category` objects:

```
new Category(self.increase,  "shoes" , 200,  .1 )
```

Then you can use `increase` in your calculation:

```
self.final = ko.computed(function() {
      return self.sales() *  increase() * self.multiplier(); 
    });
```

[See demo fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/nemesv/KAyYy/)

Comment: Thank you that does answer the question.  I was hoping I could adapt this simple answer to my more complex problem.

my data is actually coming from a json datasource so I am not sure how to add the self.increase to it